# Delete newer versions of Python 3

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04

I have multiple versions of Python 3
Python 3.7
Python 3.6
Python 3.5
I want to delete python 3.6 and 3.7 and make the 3.5 version default so that anything I install using pip gets installed in python 3.5.
When I type python3 in terminal right now, I get the 3.7 version.
OS - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Don't delete them. This can break your system. Just create an alias in your .bashrc.

Comment: I have libraries and CUDA that are configured to use python 3.5 but how do I set it as default and make pip install libraries in python 3.5

Comment: What can be does not concern me. I hate conda. What concerns me is how do I install libraries to python3.5 only using pip. When I install using pip3 right now, libraries get installed in 3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not remove the python versions as that might break my system seeing as those versions came with a software update.
Instead I used the following command to install libraries in python3.5
`python3.5 -m pip install <library-name>`

For better info :[Dealing with multiple Python versions and PIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip)

Comment: Marked the question as duplicate

Comment: My original intent was to remove the other python versions, but since that may break the system, the question is now reduced to a duplicate